# Android Emulator Redeployment Hangs

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Everytime I redeploy an android application it hangs at this step:

> [2010-12-14 09:48:40 - HelloWorld] Uploading HelloWorld.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>
> [2010-12-14 09:48:49 - HelloWorld] Installing HelloWorld.apk...

If I then go into the DDMS, I can kill the process (by hitting the stop sign) and then it finishes and launches the application.  Any idea how to fix this?  I've rebuilt the emulator, rebuilt the workspace etc with the same behavior.  I'm using Eclipse build 20100218-1602

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to uninstall the app if it already exists on your phone,

on the phone 
Menu > Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > find the app and then click the "uninstall" button

or with adb

adb uninstall [-k]  - remove this app package from the device
('-k' means keep the data and cache directories)

checkout this link http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html on running apps on devices or emulators

Automatic and manual target modes
By default, a run configuration uses the automatic target mode in order to select an AVD. In this mode, ADT will select an AVD for the application in the following manner:

If there's a device or emulator already running and its AVD configuration meets the requirements of the application's build target, the application is installed and run upon it.
If there's more than one device or emulator running, each of which meets the requirements of the build target, a "device chooser" is shown to let you select which device to use.
If there are no devices or emulators running that meet the requirements of the build target, ADT looks at the available AVDs. If one meets the requirements of the build target, the AVD is used to launch a new emulator, upon which the application is installed and run.
If all else fails, the application will not be run and you will see a console error warning you that there is no existing AVD that meets the build target requirements.
However, if a "preferred AVD" is selected in the run configuration, then the application will always be deployed to that AVD. If it's not already running, then a new emulator will be launched.

If your run configuration uses manual mode, then the "device chooser" is presented every time that your application is run, so that you can select which AVD to use.

Comment: Hi Slim.  Thanks for the quick response.  This removes it from the emulator, but it still hangs everytime I try and do a new deploy.  The issue is really with multiple redeploy's it hangs on the launch step.

Comment: maybe a "adb kill-server" and then a "adb start-server"... does that help it at all ?

Comment: also i would double check that the API you’re developing against is really available on the emulator

Comment: It doesn't.  What's interesting is if I flip to the debug prospective in Eclipse I can see my application listed twice in the debug view.  If I kill it via DDMS it then dissapears and correctly redeploys.  I think Eclipse is obviously having problems with killing the previous deployment.  Thanks again for the responses.

Comment: I found out the issue.  Turns out if I had the physical device plugged in it deploys everytime.  If I take it out, it doesn't.  The emulator must be confused on where to deploy it to.  If I leave the phone plugged in, solves the problems.

Comment: nice, glad you figured it out